# how to set up a database for laravel 5? (connection refused error)

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get a [laravel5-example](https://github.com/bestmomo/laravel5-example) project working. One of the steps seems very basic but I do not know how to do it:

```
Create a database and inform .env
```

With laravel 5 my **.env** file looks like:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=B0ST6bRoqxVJ2JtUNPtittJup6mRJef2

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=laravel_base
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

When I try to seed the database I get an error:

```
   $ php artisan migrate --seed


  [PDOException]                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

How do I create a database so I can run my laravel application on my mac? I have postgres installed. The default for this application is mysql (`'default' => 'mysql'`) in **config/database.php**. If I change it to `'default' => 'pgsql'` I get a different error:

```
$ php artisan migrate --seed


[PDOException]         
could not find driver
```

I don't really care if I have mysql or psql database, just want it to work. Mysql is the default though, so might be better to stick with that. What are the commands to set up mysql/psql databases for laravel projects?

Comment: What does the `pgsql` connection look like. Also is `pgsql` set as your `default connecftion`

Comment: `$ psql`
`psql: FATAL:  database "connorleech" does not exist`

Comment: In your laravel database.php file, what does `pgsql => `look like? and is `'default' => 'pgsql'` set?

Comment: the default is set to mysql. When I change it to psql I get a different error: `[PDOException]`        
  `could not find driver`.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure:

- You have in your `php.ini` PDO PostgreSQL enabled (`extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` not starting with `;`)
- Set in `.env` DB_CONNECTION to `pgsql` (or `default` do `pgsql` in `config/database.php` depending what specific version of Laravel you use (5.0 or 5.1/5.2))

If you won't be able to make it work, you should think of installing [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) that has everything needed to develop Laravel applications